# JWT Signature validation failed .NET 8

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I am trying to implement authentication/authorization using JWT Token with .NET 8 and Clean Architecture, but I encoutered problem which stopped me further work. I really appreciate any advices and helps.

The issue is that I have token which i get from UserController, and then when I want to fetch data (using postman) from [Authorize] method I have errors. Below is all needed information (I think so). If you are interested, then I am leaving here link to my github https://github.com/szymonJag/Chatter_v1

I have error like below:

```
[13:57:08 INF] Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
[13:57:08 INF] Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
```

How I generate token:

```
internal sealed class JwtProvider : IJwtProvider { private readonly JwtOptions _options;

     public JwtProvider(IOptions<JwtOptions> options)
     {
         _options = options.Value;
     }

     public string Generate(Domain.Entities.User.User user)
     {
         var claims = new Claim[]
         {
             new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString()),
         };

         var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
             new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                 Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_options.SecretKey)),
             SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

         var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
             _options.Issuer,
             _options.Audience,
             claims,
             null,
             DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
             signingCredentials);

         string tokenValue = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

         return tokenValue;
     }
 }
```

And my Token looks like this: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5NDE4ZDY5NS1iM2Q5LTQwMWEtY2ZiYS0wOGRjMjBjMDA0MjkiLCJleHAiOjE3MDY2MjM1NzYsImlzcyI6Ik15SXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiTXlBdWRpZW5jZSJ9.d2xjmmYsImL_2Nr0sFc6SRTEOYuo9EY-hnl2p2jlwz4`

How I configured my JWT:

```
public class JwtOptions
{
    public string Issuer { get; init; }
    public string Audience { get; init; }
    public string SecretKey { get; init; }
}
```

```
 public class JwtOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<JwtOptions>
 {
     private const string SectionName = "Jwt";
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

     public JwtOptionsSetup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         _configuration = configuration;
     }

     public void Configure(JwtOptions options)
     {
         _configuration.GetSection(SectionName).Bind(options);
     }
 }
```

```
public class JwtBearerOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private readonly JwtOptions _options;

    public JwtBearerOptionsSetup(IOptions<JwtOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = _options.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = _options.Audience,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_options.SecretKey))
        };
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//...all services

builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<JwtOptionsSetup>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, JwtBearerOptionsSetup>();

//..rest of configurations and services

app.Run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the validate the JWT token code in your API program.cs:

```
// here we specify our authentication settings to validate the JWT token
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"]))
    };
});
```